# Matching a nickname to a name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes: one with **full names** and another with **nicknames**. The nickname is always a portion of the person's full name, and the data is not sorted or indexed, so I can't just merge the two.

What I want as an output is one data frame that contains the full name and the associated nick name by simple search: find the nickname inside the name and match it.

Any solutions to this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fullName': ['Claire Daines', 'Damian Lewis', 'Mandy Patinkin', 'Rupert Friend', 'F. Murray Abraham']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nickName': ['Rupert','Abraham','Patinkin','Daines','Lewis']})
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with strings joined by `|` for regex `or` with `\b` for words boundaries:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['nickName'])
df['nickName'] = df['fullName'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df)
            fullName  nickName
0      Claire Daines    Daines
1       Damian Lewis     Lewis
2     Mandy Patinkin  Patinkin
3      Rupert Friend    Rupert
4  F. Murray Abraham   Abraham
```

Comment: nice one with word boundaries +1 didn't think to use that.